# SQL Server create Unpivot table with where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

Here is my sample table

```
---+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Id|  CompanyName|part1_sales_amount|part2_sales_amount|part3_sales_amount|part1_sales_quantity|part2_sales_quantity|part3_sales_quantity|
+---+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|   FastCarsCo|                 1|                 2|                 3|                   4|                   5|                   6|
|  2|TastyCakeShop|                 4|                 5|                 6|                   4|                   5|                   6|
|  3|     KidsToys|                 7|                 8|                 9|                   7|                   8|                   9|
|  4|   FruitStall|                10|                11|                12|                  10|                  11|                  12|
+---+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Here is output table that i want

```
+---+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Id|  CompanyName|Account           |amount            |quantity          |
+---+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  1|   FastCarsCo|       part1_sales|                 1|                 1| 
|  1|   FastCarsCo|       part2_sales|                 2|                 2|
|  1|   FastCarsCo|       part3_sales|                 3|                 3|
|  2|TastyCakeShop|       part1_sales|                 4|                 4|
|  2|TastyCakeShop|       part2_sales|                 5|                 5| 
|  2|TastyCakeShop|       part3_sales|                 6|                 6| 
|  3|     KidsToys|       part1_sales|                 7|                 7|
|  3|     KidsToys|       part2_sales|                 8|                 8|
|  3|     KidsToys|       part3_sales|                 9|                 9|
|  4|   FruitStall|       part1_sales|                10|                10|
|  4|   FruitStall|       part2_sales|                11|                11|
|  4|   FruitStall|       part3_sales|                12|                12| 
+---+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Things I already did

```
SELECT 
Id,
CompanyName,
REPLACE ( acc , '_amount' , '' ) AS Account,
amount,
quantity
FROM
(
SELECT Id, CompanyName, part1_sales_amount ,part2_sales_amount ,part3_sales_amount ,part1_sales_quantity ,part2_sales_quantity ,part3_sales_quantity 
FROM privot
) src

UNPIVOT
(
amount FOR acc IN (part1_sales_amount ,part2_sales_amount ,part3_sales_amount )
) pvt1

UNPIVOT
(
quantity FOR acc1 IN (part1_sales_quantity, part2_sales_quantity, part3_sales_quantity )
) pvt2
```

It gave some result but it seems like there is some unexpected record also(Like cross join). so my final step the `WHERE` clause, what should I write in `WHERE` clause.I tried many thing but non is a correct one.

Note: In my real data base here are almost 200 column like those part1_sales_amount and part1_sales_quantity

Please any help appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single unpivot and choose the corresponding quantity column:

```
declare @privot table
(
    id int,
    CompanyName varchar(20),
    part1_sales_amount money,
    part2_sales_amount money,   
    part3_sales_amount money,   
    part4_sales_amount money,
    part5_sales_amount money,
    part1_sales_quantity int,       
    part2_sales_quantity int,
    part3_sales_quantity int,
    part4_sales_quantity int,
    part5_sales_quantity int    

);

insert into @privot
(
    Id, CompanyName, 
    part1_sales_amount, part2_sales_amount, part3_sales_amount, part4_sales_amount, part5_sales_amount,
    part1_sales_quantity, part2_sales_quantity, part3_sales_quantity, part4_sales_quantity, part5_sales_quantity
)   
values
(1, 'FastCarsCo', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
(2, 'TastyCakeShop', 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100),
(3, 'KidsToys', 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91, 101),
(4, 'FruitStall', 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000);

select 
    Id, CompanyName, replace(acc, '_amount', '') as acc, amount, 
    quantity=choose(/*try_cast ??*/replace(left(acc, charindex('_', acc)-1), 'part', ''), /*quantity columns*/part1_sales_quantity, part2_sales_quantity, part3_sales_quantity, part4_sales_quantity, part5_sales_quantity)    
FROM
(
SELECT *
    --Id, CompanyName, 
    --part1_sales_amount, part2_sales_amount, part3_sales_amount, part4_sales_amount, part5_sales_amount,
    --part1_sales_quantity ,part2_sales_quantity ,part3_sales_quantity , part4_sales_quantity, part5_sales_quantity
FROM @privot
) src
UNPIVOT
(
amount FOR acc IN (/*amount columns*/part1_sales_amount ,part2_sales_amount ,part3_sales_amount, part4_sales_amount, part5_sales_amount )
) pvt1;
```

Comment: Nice and excellent, @Iptr could you please explain `quantity=choose(/*try_cast ??*/replace(left(acc, charindex('_', acc)-1), 'part', '')` that part I am bit confused whats that for.

Comment: after unpivot acc will be like "part2_sales_quantity" .. the string manipulation replace(left(etc) gets the 2 [you could use substring or ..]. choose(2, part1_sales_quantity, part2_sales_quantity, part3_sales_quantity..) gets the value of the 2nd column in the list [**ordering/appearance of columns  in choose is important**]. For part100_sales_quantity (after unpivot), string manipulation gets 100, choose(100, part1_sales_quantity,.....part100_sales_quantity,...part200_sales_quantity) gets the 100th column.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `apply` :

```
select t.id, t.companyname, tt.amount, tt.qty
from table t cross apply
     ( values (t.part1_sales_amount, t.part1_sales_quantity),
              (t.part2_sales_amount, t.part2_sales_quantity),
              (t.part3_sales_amount, t.part3_sales_quantity),
               . . .    
     ) tt(amount, qty);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I edited my que,there are almost 200 column in my real database, so I am trying unpivot option here. can you please help me with this?

Comment: @SohelReza . . . I think this is much better than `unpivot` -- and much better for you to learn about lateral joins (`apply` in SQL Server) than the bespoke `unpivot` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Id, CompanyName, account, amount, quantity
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT account = 'part1_sales_amount', amount = part1_sales_amount, quantity = part1_sales_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT account = 'part2_sales_amount', amount = part2_sales_amount, quantity = part2_sales_quantity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT account = 'part3_sales_amount', amount = part3_sales_amount, quantity = part3_sales_quantity
) AS AnotherData
```